# Spring execption:org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table post

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

When I try to create a new table in my database throw spring I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table post (id bigint not null, anons varchar(255), fulltext varchar(255), title varchar(255), views integer not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
```

It is due to this:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(255), title varchar(255), views integer not null, primary key (id)) engi' at line 1
```

My Post Class:

```
package com.coursework.CourseWork.Models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title, anons, fulltext;
    private int views;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAnons() {
        return anons;
    }

    public void setAnons(String anons) {
        this.anons = anons;
    }

    public String getFulltext() {
        return fulltext;
    }

    public void setFulltext(String fulltext) {
        this.fulltext = fulltext;
    }

    public int getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public void setViews(int views) {
        this.views = views;
    }
}
```

And application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/courseWork?useSSL=false&useUTF-8=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=pavel
spring.datasource.password=T@@f4ck2002
```

I look throw my code about 4 hours and still can't understand why I have SyntaxError. Just want to know what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`fulltext ia keyword in mysql, a type of index.`**

As you are using fulltext as a column name in entity, change it to something else, it should work.

Or you can also use @column annotation to give a specific name to the column without changing field name.